# I want to create a signup Form with n number of UITextFields in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: swift

I m creating a `UITableViewCell` which can display n numbers of `UITextfields`.Please suggest me how to declare these textfields . And also mention how to implement the cellForRowAt function for it.

Heres my `UITableViewCell` file

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textlab: UITextField!

    func configure(text: String?, placeholder: String) {
        textlab.text = text
        textlab.placeholder = placeholder
        textlab.accessibilityValue = text
        textlab.accessibilityLabel = placeholder
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var underlineLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var AlertMessage: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {            
        super.awakeFromNib()            
        // Initialization code            
    }
}
```

AND THE VIEW CONTROLLER FOR IT IS AS FOLLOWS:

```
import UIKit

class CustomViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    var blanklabel = ["","","",""]
    var textfields = ["First Name","Last Name","Email","Contact Number"]
    var alertmsg   = ["Please enter your First Name","Please enter your Last Name","Please enter your Email","Please enter your Contact number",]
    var textfield = UITextField()
    var AlertMessage = UILabel()

    @IBAction func nextLabel(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 4
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        return cell

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        return nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }    
}
```

Comment: I think you'll find you get much better answers if you get specific about what you have tried and what doesn't work. Good luck - and welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It's not good idea to do it in UITableView with dynamic cells. Try to use custom view (change your cell class to subclass of UIView) in UIStackView or UITableView with static cells. And set uitextfields as properties in your viewcontroller.